# SAPUI5 - network graph label on line between nodes

Tags: sapui5

I checked the [documentation of SAPUI5 Line controller](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph.Line) of a network graph, yet I didn't find a way to a add a label in or within a line. Is something like this even possibel in SAPUI5?

expected result image
[image]

Edit:
And I'm not meaning the focus or the hover functionality.

Comment: You can add a popover when pressing on the line: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.commons.networkgraph.Graph/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.NetworkGraphCustomPopup

Comment: I find this not helpful, bringing up the information by clicking on the line. I want it to be visible on the line, without focus or hover functionality.